# How can i sum up all numbers in a textfile?

Tags: c, file, sum, numbers, text-files

I have a Problem by summing up all numbers from a Textfile. It may seem simple but the Problem is that my Code does not recognize 2000 as 2000 but as 2,0,0,0 so it will se the number as 4 seperate numbers:

I tried to read the Textfile one letter as a time since I also wanted to Count how  many times a letter appears

This is the text I wanted to read:

Die Ruhr-Universität Bochum (RUB) in Bochum ist mit 42954 Studierenden (Stand WS 2018/19) eine der zehn größten Universitäten in Deutschland.

Die RUB war 1962 (Aufnahme des Lehrbetriebs 1965) die erste Universitätsneugründung in der Bundesrepublik.
Die Universität wurde außerhalb der Stadt als Campus-Universität in Querenburg angelegt: Bis auf wenige Außenstellen sind alle Fakultäten auf dem Universitätsgelände untergebracht.
Die Universität, die Wohnstadt Hustadt und das beide versorgende Einkaufszentrum Uni-Center dominieren seither den Stadtteil.

```
int main()
{
char txtname[2000];
FILE *fp;
int buchstaben[26] = {0};
int i;
int temp;
int sum;


printf("Dateiname:\n");

scanf("%s",&txtname);

printf("%s",&txtname);

strcat(txtname,".txt");

fp = fopen(txtname,"r");




if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
}else {
    while( (temp=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
        if(temp >= 'a' ||  temp <= 'z')
         buchstaben[(temp - 'a')]++;
         if( temp >= 'A' || temp <= 'Z')
         buchstaben[(temp - 'A')]++;
         if(temp>= 48 || temp<= 57)
    }
    printf("Anzahl der einzelnen Buchstaben: \n");

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)

    printf("Buchstabe %c kommt %d mal vor.\n",i+'a',buchstaben[i]);
    }
    printf("Die Summe aller Zahlen sind:%d",sum);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Your `||` (ORs) should be `&&` (ANDs). E.g.: `temp >= 'a' ||  temp <= 'z'` should be `temp >= 'a' &&  temp <= 'z'` Think about it: a letter less than `a` will still be considered OK because it still is less than `z`.

Comment: Ah yes you are Right i though These were the same things

Comment: Your last if, `if(temp>= 48 || temp<= 57)` should generate a compiler warning because it is not followed by a statement. Turn warnings of your compiler on.

Comment: Im still a noob  :D

Comment: Don;t use constants like 48 and 57 but use chars `'0'` and `'9'`

Comment: Yes I know im still figuring out what im doing if my temp becomes a number this is why it is currently not followed with a statement

Comment: And do NOT edit your code with the errors reported because then we can't help you anymore as possible a cause of the problem is gone.

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there a place where you are summing up all numbers. What is your question? What is your problem?

Comment: Oh okay it is my first Question iam sorry

Comment: I tried many different Things but i deleted them could u tell me how i can extract the numbers out of the text i given and sum them all up together. My Problem is that my Code sees 2000 as 4 seperate numbers but i want the Code to put 2000 as 2000 in an Array and than summarise all numbers with a for loop . Im sorry it is my first Question I do not know how to exactly state my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop reads one character at a time. When you see a digit, you must read all digits and turn them into a number while reading the digits.

One way to do that is, following your `if(temp>= '0' && temp<= '9')` to loop reading chars and processing the digits.

However, the last character you read now is *not* a digit. Then you end your digit reading loop but now your outer loop has a problem because a character was read but not yet processed. To fix that, use `ungetc` (look it up in the documentation).

```
if(temp>= '0' && temp<= '9') {
    int number= temp-'0';
    while ((temp= fgetc(fp))>='0' && temp <='9')
        number= number * 10 + (temp-'0');
    ungetc(temp,fp);
    sum += number;
}
```

Reading a number '20' you first read `2`. The next digit you see means the number you have already read is a ten-fold so you multiply it with ten. Then you turn the ASCII digit into a decimal number by subtracting `'0'` and add it to the number you have read already. Note that the ASCII code ensures that the digit characters are in the order `'0,'1','2',...'9'` so `'3' - '0' = 3`

Comment: Why do i multiply the number with 10 and also thank you for the help

Comment: can u explain the 4th line ?

Comment: The Compiler says that there too few Arguments for ungetc(fp)

Comment: Ah...the compiler is right. Look up `ungetc` in the documentation and fix my error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi, it converts string to an integer, when it comes accross non integer char, it stops:

```
int sum=0;
if (temp >= '0' && temp <= '9') {
    sum += atoi(temp);
    while (temp >= '0' && temp <= '9') {
        temp=fgetc(fp); //skip the rest of the number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bin auch an der RUB, kann man dich zufällig irgendwo kontaktieren? Discord oder so? Hab das selbe Problem wie du aber komme nicht weiter.

Comment: Ja hab nen Discord warte kurz